# Dúvida com sockets(WinSocks)

Tags: c, socket

Boas,

Ando a aprender como trabalhar com sockets(nunca trabalhei) e decidi começar por winsocks. De momento estou a utilizar `winsock2.h` e no tutorial que estou a seguir cheguei a uma parte que não consigo compreender como funciona.

[AQUI ESTÁ O TUTORIAL](http://www.binarytides.com/code-tcp-socket-server-winsock/)

A parte que tenho duvida é como é feito o handle dos diversos clientes.

```
 //add master socket to fd set
    FD_SET(master, &readfds);
       //add child sockets to fd set
    for (  i = 0 ; i < max_clients ; i++) 
    {
        s = client_socket[i];
        if(s > 0)
        {
            FD_SET( s , &readfds);
        }
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(master , &readfds)) 
 {....}
```

Porque razão este `if statement` não é sempre verdadeiro e como funciona? O socket `master` está sempre definido. No inicio pensei que era porque se fazia `set`aos sockets dos clientes, mas nenhum deles é superior a 0.

Comment: Recomendo usar uma biblioteca crossplataform, como o boost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tutorial, antes do if em questão existe uma chamada para a função select. A função select vai alterar os bits de `readfds` de acordo com a presença ou não de atividade no respectivo `socket`. É por este motivo que, mesmo com o código setando o bit correspondente ao `socket` "master", após a chamada para select este bit pode ser resetado, e o if pode não ser verdadeiro.